# Unit tests not reading endpoint from web.config on 'Debug selected tests'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, web-config

I have a MVC project and a unit testing project in the same solution.  The unit tests create instances of classes in the MVC project that read a service bus endpoint from the MVC's `web.config` file.

There are two different endpoint entries, one points to a test server and the other points to localhost for testing code on my machine.  Usually the localhost entry is commented out.

Alright, so the issue I'm having is this:  When I un-comment the localhost entry and comment out the dev server entry and run a specific test (using "Run Selected Tests"), the test are still pointing at the development server's entry (commented out) in the config file... even if I re-build the solution.  If I run the application, it reads the correct entry and points to localhost.

How can I force individual unit tests to read the `web.config` to get the correct values?

Comment: Unit tests will run under the context of the assembly where the tests reside. Assuming that your tests are in a different project than the web site, you'll need to create an app.config file in the test project. Whatever you are testing will look in that file for configuration.

Comment: Ah, I assumed that the unit tests would look to the config of the project that was being tested.  Thanks @Keith!  If you want to post an answer I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unit tests will run under the context of the assembly where the tests reside. Assuming that your tests are in a different project than the web site, you'll need to create an app.config file in the test project.

Whatever you are testing will look in that file for configuration.